# Why NSLog prints different strings from same NSDate object

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I'm using Xcode 9.3. I have code like this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];

    NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
}
```

Output is :

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
```

Can someone explain why those two outputs are different and how second NSLog line works under the hood? I thought that `NSLog(@"%@", date);` is calling description, but it seems that it's not the case anymore or I'm missing something.

Comment: Just for correction in making the date object. `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]` should be `[NSDate date]`

Comment: May be `NSLog` uses `dateFormatter` to convert a `date` object to `string` and then print.

Comment: @TheTiger No, `NSLog` doesn't use a date formatter.

Comment: NSLog uses the new unified logging system and doesn't call description on NSDate objects anymore.

Comment: My observations (macOS 10.13.4): `timeIntervalSince1970` is called and the result is used in `ctime()`.